# HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath resolved as "/" on develop server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

to get some images' path server side i use HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath to build up a correct path.

It works on the production environment, but it gets resolved as "/" on the developement / debug server provided by VS2008.

Comment: '/' is expected if the application is on the root of the domain, what are you expecting? is your application in a folder? the folder needs to be defined as an application for you to get the folder name in the ApplicationPath.

Comment: This is happening to me as well. It was working just fine under Vista 32-bit, but I recently upgraded my machine to Windows 7 64-bit and it started doing this. I'm going with Akash's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`HttpContext.Curent.Server.MapPath("/*****");` <- this will give you correct path..

Answer (score 0):

Just use `HttpServerUtility.MapPath("~/images")`. The "~" denotes application root.